# map from Char to String in Haskell

Tags: haskell, transliteration

I'm trying to figure out how to [improve the transliteration](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3757) from German umlauts to ASCII for `id` identifiers in Pandoc. Currently there is only a mapping `Char -> Maybe Char`, that converts `ä` into `a` and `ß` into `Nothing` etc., but the most common convention maps `ä` into `ae` and `ß` into `ss` and so on. Here is what I have so far:

```
import Data.Char (isAscii)
import qualified Data.Map as M

asciiMap' :: M.Map Char String
asciiMap' = M.fromList
  [('\196',"Ae")
  ,('\214',"Oe")
  ,('\220',"Ue")
  ,('\223',"ss")
  ,('\228',"ae")
  ,('\246',"oe")
  ,('\252',"ue")
  ]

toAsciiStr :: Char -> String
toAsciiStr c | isAscii c = [c]
             | otherwise = M.findWithDefault "" c asciiMap'

myTranslit :: String -> String
myTranslit [] = []
myTranslit (x:xs) = toAsciiStr x ++ myTranslit xs
```

My question is about `myTranslit`.

Is there maybe already a built-in *map*-like function `someMap :: (a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is [**`concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap), that concatenates the output after mapping. Since `[]` is a `Foldable`, it thus can *specialize* in `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`, and further (with `a ~ Char` and `b ~ Char`) into `concatMap :: (Char -> [Char]) -> [Char] -> [Char]`. Note that `String` is an alias for `type String = [Char]` so, a `String` is nothing more that a list of `Char`acters.

You can thus use:

```
myTranslit :: String -> String
myTranslit = concatMap toAsciiStr
```

Comment: Great. I tried along with your edit and now it works :)

Comment: I was aware that `String` is `[Char]` and was actually expecting a function of the type `:: (a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]` maybe I should edit the question

Answer (score 4):

You can make the entire thing as concise as

```
myTranslit :: String -> String
myTranslit = concatMap $ \c -> case c of
  'Ä' -> "Ae"
  'Ö' -> "Oe"
  'Ü' -> "Ue"
  'ä' -> "ae"
  'ö' -> "oe"
  'ü' -> "ue"
  'ß' -> "ss"
  _ | isAscii c  = [c]
    | otherwise  = ""
```

Comment: ...interesting option especially in my case, the integration into Pandoc has to be changed anyway.